# Regular Expression in PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Can someone help me to use the regular expression in sql for the following scenario

Need to check if any string/symbols(Other than number) value comes in for specific column then it should throw an error or anything. Currently have used

to_number(column) - but it is not throwing error if it only starts with string otherwise it is allowing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out below are the different scenario with REGEX as well as TO_NUMBER function.

**REXEX valid Number scenario:**

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('1234', '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '');
1234
```

**REXEX invalid number scenario:**

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('AS1234#$', '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '');
no data found

SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('$', '^\d+(\.\d+)?$', '');
no data found
```

**TO_NUMBER valid scenario:**

```
select to_number('123') from dual;
```

**TO_NUMBER invalid scenario:**

```
select to_number('123d') from dual;
select to_number('.23.') from dual;
select to_number('asdf') from dual;

ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: One more help, if I pass null value,  is it possible to throw any error/msg instead of null

Comment: Not, because null can be converted into any data type. for that, you can add an extra case statement to handle only for null values.

Comment: If answer is useful you can voteup and mark it answered.

Comment: Okay got it. Instead of in where clause, is there any way to assign the regular expressions to any value. Something like this

Comment: Yes sure, you can.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `check` constraint on the column.  This would look like:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col
    check (regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]*$'));
```

A `check` constraint will have the *database* validate the data for you.  This is the best way to implement such a check to ensure data integrity.